# dnspy disassembly code async method gives syntax error

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dnspy

When I decompile the exe file, it gives a spelling errors.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDp0b.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDp0b.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the decompiled code as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Comment: Anyway those look like internal, hidden members and classes generated by the c# compiler when it converts `async` code into a state machine.  See https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/878930/Internal-Implementation-of-Async-Methods-in-NET-Pa.  I believe the compiler uses invalid identifier names for such internally generated stuff so as to not conflict with identifiers used in the code.

Comment: `Options->Decompiler->C#->Show hidden decompiler generated classes and methods`